# Arduino as xcos block

Tags: arduino, scilab, xcos

I am developing an interface between Arduino microcontroller and Scilab (analogue of MATLAB) simulation environment. 
How I see it:

A graphical block representing Arduino in Scilab. It will have 6 analogue and 14 digital inputs on the left side of the block and 14 digital outputs on the right side.

The interface that should be developed which:

1. gets output values from physical Arduino and assigns to the outputs of the graphical block in Scilab;
2. gets inputs from graphical block and assigns them to the inputs of the physical Arduino.

Could anyone give me ideas how I could do it?

Comment: I'm not sure that xcos can be used to interface to a real, physical system (an Arduino in this case). Is that what you are wanting to do or are you looking at a way to simulate an Arduino?

Comment: Both. Simulate by interfacing

Comment: take a look at SimulIDE, KTechLab, MyOpenLab, SimulAVR, simavr, OpenModelica...

Comment: coming back to this post :) take a look at the library I'm developing: https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/44fe9b5e2bcb02b22392adf6d8f7a871

Answer (score 0):

There's an atoms for Arduino Communication through Serial : http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/arduino

Answer (score 0):

Arduion communicate with serial port; SciLab have serial port tool, you need to establish the link between them. In Arduino-MATLAB communication some code need to be in Arduino memory before the communication start so the same would be between Arduion-SciLab.